# Translate t-sql query to LINQ (left join with subquery/nested right join)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Here's query that I've managed to write:

```
select *
from [Transaction] as t left join (ProductTransaction as pt right join Product as p on pt.productId = p.productId) on t.transactionId = pt.transactionId
                    left join (ReservationTransaction as rt right join Reservations as r on rt.reservationId = r.reservationId) on t.transactionId = rt.transactionId
```

So far I've got something like this (without nested right joins) and I'm stuck. Could anyone help me with these subquery/nested joins ?

```
from t in dataContext.Transactions
                join pt in dataContext.ProductTransactions on t.transakcja_id equals pt.transactionId into pTransactions
                from pt in pTransactions.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join rt in dataContext.ReservationTransactions on t.transakcja_id equals rt.transactionId into rTransactions
                from rt in rTransactions.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

EDIT: 
OK, thanks for the tips. What i'm trying to do is to combine ~5 entieties, which are related (they're connected with foreign keys), into one table. The case is I need all Transaction but not every transaction is connected to product or reservation. So I'm not sure if i'll be able to get all of them using simple associetion properties and much more queries than one or am I ? Maybe I should use more than one query and have the problem of my chest ?

I uploaded a screenshot of entieties scheme that I'm working on. Thanks in advance for your advices. [part of db scheme](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/transactionsdbscheme.png/) <-- Couldn't upload on stackoverflow cause of my low reputation points

Comment: For what I can tell you, you'd better explain in clear words what your query needs to do, and then reason it in LINQ instead of trying to translate it from sql. Joseph Albahari explained on his site why trying to translate from SQL is such a bad idea. Apart from this, if those tables have FKs correctly set you don't need to join anything, just query the main table and navigate through navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

Setup foreign keys in your database, you will not need joins, you'll access linked tables with association properties like that (just a exemple):

> var transation = dataContact.Transations.First();
>
> var price = transaction.ProductTransaction.Product.Price;

Comment: Indeed, translating from sql is a bad idea. They both share the same common thing, Relational Algebra. However it's implementation is much better in LINQ. So it is better to find out what the query should return and recreate it in linq.

Comment: Using linq syntax you have two options, query syntax
`var q = from el in dataSource where el.prop == condition select new { /*your projection including navigation properties*/ };`
and Enuerable extensions
`var q = dataSource.Where(x=>x.prop == condition).Select(x=> new {/*projection*/}).Skip(20).Take(20)`